# set innerHtml from a sanitized html is still dangerous?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

There is a replacement for innerHtml in react: dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Its name scares me.

In the React documents I read that:

In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

But I sanitized my html with dompurify.
Does this completely protect me from XSS attacks?

Comment: No. Nothing is 100% secure.

Comment: yes of course. Can I combine dompurify with other libraries to improve security? what do you think about it?

Comment: Sure. Mitigation is a good strategy, but it's not 100% secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I sanitized my html with dompurify. Does this completely protect me from XSS attacks?

Likely yes, but it's not 100% guaranteed. If DOMPurify doesn't have bugs that will let XSS through, setting `innerHTML` or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with its results will be safe. DOMPurify is open-source and relatively popular, so if it *did* have such vulnerabilities, they would probably have been seen by now.

But, like with everything humans do, mistakes and coincidences that result in vulnerabilities not being seen are still possible.

Comment: Can I combine dompurify with other libraries to improve security? what do you think about it?

Comment: I suppose you *could*, but I'd be quite doubtful of if that'd be of any use. The logic needed to prevent XSS in general is pretty easy AFAIK. (1) Remove script tags (and maybe iframes) (2) Remove inline -on handlers (3) Remove styles too, if desired. It's nearly trivial to implement yourself even, though a trusted library is a better choice. If it were me, I'd be happy going just with DOMPurify. Feel free to run and examine their [test suite](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/main/test/test-suite.js) if real money is involved.

Answer (score 3):

> Its name scares me.

It's supposed to. :-)

> But I sanitized my html with dompurify. Does this completely protect me from XSS attacks?

It [claims to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify):

> DOMPurify sanitizes HTML and prevents XSS attacks. You can feed DOMPurify with string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string (unless configured otherwise) with clean HTML. DOMPurify will strip out everything that contains dangerous HTML and thereby prevent XSS attacks and other nastiness.

Whether you believe the claim is really your call to make. That said, sanitizing HTML is a well-studied problem so it's certainly *possible* to do. I make no claims for that particular library, which I haven't used or audited.